# XSLT program to convert source to target

Tags: xml, xslt, soap, xslt-1.0

I'm not experienced with xslt and hence the request to help on my problem.

Bascially I send a soap request to a 3rd party service and I get the below response

***Response from 3rd party for a successful message***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<nm:Response xmlns:nm="http://fsag.de/BusinessTransaction">
<BTEMessage>
  <InOrderContext>
     <SendTimestamp>01-06-2017:0506230000</SendTimestamp>
  </InOrderContext>
  <SystemContext>
    <Client>FDP</Client>
    <CorrelationId>34553FTG25543SFD134</CorrelationId>
    <BusinessContext>RECONCL</BusinessContext>
  </SystemContext>
</BTEMessage>
```

but when there is a fault in the xml the webservice is returned with a soap fault as below:

***Fault message from 3rd party***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<nm:Response xmlns:nm="http://fsag.de/BusinessTransaction">
<env:Envelope  xmlns:env="http://www.w3.org/2001/12/soap-envelope" >
    <env:Body>
        <env:Fault>

          <env:Code>
            <env:Value>env:Sender</env:Value>
          </env:Code>

          <env:Reason>
            <env:Text xml:lang="en-US">Processing error</env:Text>
            <env:Text xml:lang="da">Processerings-fejl</env:Text>
          </env:Reason>

        </env:Fault>
    </env:Body>
</env:Envelope>
</nm:Response>
```

So basically I need to have one XSLT program that would produce the target as below:

***If not fault message target to be as:***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<nm:BTEMessage xmlns:nm="http://fsag.de/BusinessTransaction">
  <InOrderContext>
     <SendTimestamp>20170601095410 </SendTimestamp>
  </InOrderContext>
  <SystemContext>
    <Client>BTD</Client>
    <CorrelationId>C67DCFBC3C031ED791D3F050E6E1C0DA</CorrelationId>
    <BusinessContext>Collections</BusinessContext>
  </SystemContext>
</nm:BTEMessage>
```

**but if a SOAP fault  is returned then the target to be as**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <nm:Response xmlns:nm="http://fsag.de/BusinessTransaction">
    <BTEMessage>
      <InOrderContext>
         <SendTimestamp></SendTimestamp>
      </InOrderContext>
      <SystemContext>
        <Client></Client>
        <CorrelationId></CorrelationId>
        <BusinessContext></BusinessContext>
      </SystemContext>
    </BTEMessage>
    <env:Envelope  xmlns:env="http://www.w3.org/2001/12/soap-envelope" >
        <env:Body>
            <env:Fault>
              <env:Code>
                <env:Value>env:Sender</env:Value>
              </env:Code>
             <env:Reason>
     <env:Text xml:lang="en-US">Processing error</env:Text>
            <env:Text xml:lang="da">Processerings-fejl</env:Text>
          </env:Reason>
        </env:Fault>
    </env:Body>
    </env:Envelope>
    </nm:Response>
```

Please any help here ?

So far I could get it moving as not sure where and how to start considering my very less exp in xslt. This processing is performed in SAP and with SAP providing the compatibility of XSL programs I think this would be implemented.

Comment: Produce it from what? Error where? At least to me it is quite unclear what you want to do.

Comment: Hi Sami, the soap fault is not defined in wsdl file but for any error the 3rd party send a soap fault message. So basically I want to create a target message from the response I receive from 3rd party. If the response from 3rd party has soap fault I need to create  a target which contains the format as in the above post

Comment: Please correct your code examples to be well-formed XML (add missing closing tags, fix upper/lower case mismatches, namespace discrepancies, etc.).

Comment: Also please show what you have come up with so far, and explain where you are stuck.  We expect you to at least have a go at it yourself before you ask here.

Comment: Thanks Michael and John. Updated my xml with the actual contents (though trimmed most of the elements)  . I don't have a clue on where to start and how to start and hence the post as my exp is predominantly in SAP integrations

Comment: Are you sure you need to change `<BTEMessage>` to `<nm:BTEMessage xmlns:nm="http://fsag.de/BusinessTransaction">`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply use a different template for each case:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:nm="http://fsag.de/BusinessTransaction"
xmlns:env="http://www.w3.org/2001/12/soap-envelope" 
exclude-result-prefixes="env">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="/nm:Response[BTEMessage]">
    <nm:BTEMessage>
        <xsl:copy-of select="BTEMessage/*"/>
    </nm:BTEMessage>    
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/nm:Response[env:Envelope]">
    <xsl:copy>
        <BTEMessage>
            <InOrderContext>
                <SendTimestamp/>
            </InOrderContext>
            <SystemContext>
                <Client/>
                <CorrelationId/>
                <BusinessContext/>
            </SystemContext>
        </BTEMessage>
        <xsl:copy-of select="env:Envelope"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks Michael. But when there is a SOAP fault I will not have "<BTEMessage>" in source XML and in this case I think the XSL will not produce the result I want....am I right in my understanding of the XSL?

Comment: @PrabhuSethupathy When there is a fault, you will have `env:Envelope` in the source XML - and that will cause the 2nd template to be executed. Try it to see.

Comment: Hi Michael....yes I'm with you. When there is a fault message the second template would run but the first template  "BTEMessage" will not be available in source. So in this case I want to both the first and second template, except the first template to have null value assigned to the elements.

Comment: Since the `BTEMessage` is not present in the source, there is no way to get it from there - you must include the empty elements in the stylesheet itself - as I have done.